# Convergence of numerical scheme for HJB equation

Tags: real-analysis, na.numerical-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, numerical-analysis-of-pde

Convergence of numerical scheme for HJB equation has been widely studied, the key paper is the [Barles's one](https://benjaminmoll.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/barles-souganidis.pdf). Essentially, the convergence is guarenteed if the scheme is:

- Consistent
- Stable
- Monotony

### Problem with understanding monotonicity

The author gives application to finite differences. But I am struggling for understanding the application for a discret model only w.r.t the time.

Let suppose you want to build an approximation scheme for the equation:

$$u_t = \mathcal{F(u_{xx})},~~u(0,\cdot) = u_0(\cdot) \text{  on  } [0,T]\times\mathbb{R}$$

of the following form:

$$u(t_{n+1},\cdot) = \mathcal{S}(u(t_{n},\cdot)), ~~u(t_0,\cdot) = u_0(\cdot)$$

with $(t_0 = 0,...,t_N = T)$ a subdivision of $[0,T]$. **Let suppose that this scheme is consistent and stable, what is the monotonicity condition that $\mathcal{S}$ should verify to have the convergence of the numerical scheme ?**

Thank you very much!